# All array elements undefined except the last one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

So our teacher gave us a homework. We were supposed to write a program that asks the user how many numbers they want to input, then ask them so many times to input a number, until it has all the numbers the user wanted to give. Then, the program should show or output the numbers the user formerly entered or input.
This is how I did it:

```
<html>
<script>
  amount = prompt("How many numbers do you wish to input?");
  amount1 = amount - 1;
  for (i = 0; i <= amount1; i++) {
    a = i + 1;
    var input = [];
    input[i] = prompt("Please enter the " + a + ". number:");
  }
  alert(input.toString());
</script>

</html>
```

However, the output isn't what I'd expected it would be. If we, say, enter 5 numbers, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5`, then the final result shows `,,,,5`
If I'm not mistaken, this means that all the elements, except the last one, are `undefined`. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can avoid it?

Comment: Your code resets the `input` array to `[]` on every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your `var input = [];` variable initialization out of `for` loop and you're good to go.

**Why it doesn't work for you:** As you're resetting the value of input array every time with this line `var input = [];` that's why only the last element is visible within the array :(, so when you'll move out from the loop it'll work as expected.

```js
 amount = prompt("How many numbers do you wish to input?");
  amount1 = amount - 1;
  var input = [];
  for (i = 0; i <= amount1; i++) {
    a = i + 1;
    
    input[i] = prompt("Please enter the " + a + ". number:");
  }
  alert(input.toString());
```

Comment: @CubeMage You're welcome, glad helps you some how. By the way you're not an idiot its just a mistake and we all do mistakes while coding. Best of luck :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script>
    var input = [];  
    var a = 0;

    amount = Number(prompt("How many numbers do you wish to input?"));

    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        a = i + 1;
        input[i] = Number(prompt("Please enter the " + a + ". number:"));
    }

    alert(input.toString())
</script>
</html>
```